# Embedded youtube videos - Simply play a video without audio?

Tags: javascript, jquery, video, youtube, youtube-api

**Question:**

How can I control the sound output of this embedded video without overly complicating things?

**Possible Solution (Complex)**

I've looked into the youtube javascript control API, and, correct me if I'm wrong, but that will force me to incorporate a lot of complication into the setup to accomplish what appears to be a very simple task.

**Note:**

This is all only tested for webkit at this stage

**Setup:**

I've created an element that simulates an iphone controlling the channel of a tv by swapping youtube videos like so:

```
var channel1 = "http://www.youtube.com/embed/dFU6Cy4Hd5A?autoplay=1&rel=0&controls=0&showinfo=0&disablekb=1&iv_load_policy=3&modestbranding=1";

$("#channel-1").click(function(){
    $("#tv").attr("src", channel1);
});
```

where the #channel-1 id is connected to a specific button on the remote, and the tv id is connected to the video player.

**It looks like this:**

[image]

[image]

**Edit:**

If the API is the only to accomplish this, please include a link to a comprehensive tutorial teaching the youtube web API, because I've looked, and found nothing. The only thing I've found so far is the official API page, and that's like trying to learn PHP from the manual.

Comment: You need to use API for this. And this is not complex solution at all.

Comment: @dfsq Great, can you link me to a comprehensive tutorial on using the API? I've searched, believe me, and all I've found so far is google's API page. It seems like there should be a quick video or tutorial page I could use somewhere, but so far I've come up empty handed.

Comment: I've also tried figuring out the youtube API from questions including snippets of it, and from the official API page but being new to javascript, I could really use a more comprehensive tutorial without all of the extra specific jargon. I have no problem with learning it, it's just that I prefer more.. "friendly" tutorials. Using the official API page is like trying to learn PHP straight from the manual. Can be done, but horrible experience.

Answer (score 0):

For loading videos you would use `loadVideoById` rather than the rather odd snippet you have in your question and to play without audio you simply mute the player using `player.mute()` (where player is a reference retrieved from the youtube player element itself like [described](https://developers.google.com/youtube/js_api_reference#GettingReference) here). And one last thing, don't forget to add `enablejsapi=1` to the url of the player as described [here](https://developers.google.com/youtube/player_parameters#enablejsapi).

Comment: I'm looking for a comprehensive tutorial to explain the use of loadVideoById, can you link me? I'm come up with nothing so far

Answer (score 0):

I would use

event.target.mute();